# Elegant object-oriented member access without large number of getters/mutators

Tags: c++, serialization, embedded, deserialization, object-oriented-analysis

In an embedded application I am working on, I frequently need to packetize data from several different objects to be sent out over a serial port. Similarly, data comes in on the serial port that needs to be written to several different objects.

For compatibility reasons, the ordering of the data in the packets does not allow for all the data associated with one object to be placed consecutively in the packet. So I can not easily vectorize, etc. data from each object and then put all that in a packet.

I can achieve proper functionality using a very large number of getters/mutators that the packet class uses to create/decode transmitted/received packets. But this does not seem very elegant.

I could make the packet class a friend of the classes it pulls/writes data from/to, but I was always told to avoid using friends as that sort of violates object-oriented principles.

Ideally the classes that handle the actual application would not know anything about the packet class (and not have to provide getters/mutators exclusively for it) and they simply would have new data if a packet came in between updates.

I thought that maybe I could pass references or pointers to the relevant member variables to the packet class at startup, but that is also tricky because all the members are not the same size. Perhaps I could also pass the size information as well? Would there be a way to vectorize a list of void pointer to member and size of member pairs so that the packet class does not need to take a gigantic amount of arguments to its constructor?

I am not sure how well I have described this problem, but I can certainly provide clarifications and more information if that would help. Thanks very much for any ideas.

Abbreviated example of tx packet class currently:

```
class PacketTx {
private:
  uint8_t buffer[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];   // MAX_PACKET_SIZE is 200
public:
  PacketTx(object1 *firstObject,
           object2 *secondObject,
           object3 *thirdObject
           // ...etc...
           )

  void sendPacket(void);
};

void PacketTx::sendPacket(void) {
  uint32_t i = 0;

  int16_t tempVar1 = firstObject->getVar1();
  uint32_t tempVar2 = secondObject->getVar2();
  uint8_t tempVar3 = firstObject->getVar3();
  int32_t tempVar4 = thirdObject->getVar4();
  // ...etc...

  memcpy(buffer + i, &tempVar1, sizeof(tempVar1));
  i += sizeof(tempVar1);

  memcpy(buffer + i, &tempVar2, sizeof(tempVar2));
  i += sizeof(tempVar2);

  memcpy(buffer + i, &tempVar3, sizeof(tempVar3));
  i += sizeof(tempVar3);

  memcpy(buffer + i), &tempVar4, sizeof(tempVar4));
  i += sizeof(tempVar4);

  // ...etc...

  for(uint32_t j = 0; j < i; ++j)
    putc(static_cast<char>(buffer[i]));
}
```

This example doesn't include header, checksum, etc., but it should give a basic idea of what is causing me a headache.

Comment: I think the OO way of doing this would be to teach the object to write itself to a buffer.

Comment: That is the way I used to do it. Unfortunately, because I have expanded the packets but still need backwards-compatibility, an object cannot write all the relevant member variables to a buffer, as the data will not be in consecutive locations in the final packet.

Comment: What's a "very large number"? And will it increase in the future? What are the data types you are dealing with? Are they heterogeneous? What kind of performance are you looking for?

Comment: If the class has too much info and need a lot of getters and setters. In the OO world that means you probably should break it up into smaller more manageable classes each with a different concern.

Comment: @CraigWright 50+, and yes it might increase further. The data types are not heterogeneous, but they are all primitives if that somehow helps. Performance is not so much an issue as the readability and simplicity of my code.

Comment: @ahenderson That would definitely be possible, but I am still stuck with the packet class having to use an extremely large number of getters/setters. Ideally there would be some way to execute a loop where it pulls the relevant data using pre-passed references, pointers, anything...

Comment: I would post the definition of you packet class on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and ask how you can break it up. 50+ fields for a packet has smells like bad design to me.

Comment: @ahenderson Thanks, I will consider it. The data is simply unrelated, but all sent in one packet. The packet just serializes many 1,2,4 byte primitives and ships them off all together. I could create additional packets, but I'm not sure what the point of that would be since all the data needs to be updated at the same frequency more or less.

Comment: I think this is somewhat of a naive solution, but a std::(unordered_)map<std::string, Variant/boost::any>, might work. You could then store a table (std::set or sorted std::vector perhaps) that lists all of the keys you expect in the map.  Then you just provide get and setProperty(std::string, boost::any) functions. Clearly there are drawbacks to going this way, but it might work for you.

Comment: @CraigWright Thanks very much, I will try to flush out that idea with respect to integration in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So If I understand you have Some class C which has an arbitrary number of members which need to be written out into a buffer in an arbitrary order. Then the same mechanism occurs in reverse.

Serial -> Packet.buffer() -> Object (and reverse)

My initial thought was using `boost::tuple` and having the types correspond to the order of the data in the packet. (But with possibly 50+ members/entries in tuple that could be a big compile time hit)

e.g

```
tuple<float, int, std::string> a(1.0f,  2, std::string("Some Words");
ostr << a;
```

That would also require your classes to take a tuple as an argument and fill in the entries from data. So rather than write to a buffer there could be an enumeration of the fields held in the tuple so that "nice" code could be written:

```
enum Fields {Price,Amount,Reason};
typedef boost::tuple<...> MyTuple;

void MyClass::getData( MyTuple& t )
{
    t<Price>() = mPrice;
    t<Amount>() = mAmount;
    t<Reason>() = mSomeReason;
}
```

Note Would work in reverse as well.

Not sure if this fits completely with what you were trying to do but it may trigger some new thoughts?

Comment: Thanks very much. I think that would definitely work. It would definitely be a very large tuple, but it is certainly better than what I am doing now.

Comment: Not sure I will actually implement this, but it is probably one of the best possible answers for such an annoying problem. Thanks very much.

Comment: np - I enjoyed the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Composition is what you'll need here:

```
class packet {
    enum PacketType {
        type1,
        ...
    };
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer;
    PacketType id;
public:
    void setData(std::vector<unsigned char> buffer);
    void setType(PacketType type);
    std::vector<usigned char> getData();
    PacketType getType();
    //serialize Packet;
};

class composition_packet {
    //other packet related detail.
    std::vector<packet> data;
public:
    void addPacket(packet p);
    void send();
    //serialize composition_packet
};
```

The idea here is to make multiple packets as needed but send them as one big packet (`composition_packet`). The other concept here is the packet is only responsible for serializing itself and not data types that it should know anything about. Data to the packet must be already serialized by an object that know how to serialize it.

---

```
struct foo {
   std::string str;
   uint_8 u8;
   uint_32 u32;

   packet getPacket() {
       //simple dumb serialization
       std::stringstream ss(str);
       ss << "|";  //delimit character
       ss << u8 << "|";
       ss << u32;
       std::string s(ss.str());
       std::vector<unsigned char> data(s.begin(), s.end());
       packet p;
       p.setType(packet::fooType);
       p.setData(data);
       return p;
   }

};
```

Comment: The problem is that there is literally no logical way to dissect the packet into multiple smaller ones. Think random data from multiple random objects, all of different sizes. I'm not sure it makes sense to have the objects serialize the data themselves because that data will not be consecutive in the packet.

Comment: ***"data will not be consecutive in the packet"***
I'm not sure What you mean? I'm going to give an example use case. could you point out the issue for me.

Comment: In this case, for instance, u8 and u32 are not guaranteed to be next to each other in the composition packet. The order of the data in that final packet (what is actually sent out through the serial port) is very important because right now systems have backwards compatibility.  I.e. if A and B have to talk to each other, A can still receive data from B even if A has old code, as long as new data added to B's tx stream is only tacked on at the end. You don't get the new functionality as if A and B had the same rev code (i.e. A expects the tacked-on data) but at least the system still works.

Comment: I don't understand why you believe ***"u8 and u32 are not guaranteed to be next to each other in the composition packet"***. But I understand this solution will not work if you have backwards comparability as a constraint.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain that very well. I just meant that it is possible that u8 was in the transmitted packet in an earlier version of code, with other items behind it. Then to add a new feature maybe I tacked u32 on as well. So now there is stuff between u8 and u32, even though they both belong to foo. This makes it impossible for foo to properly serialize its own members.

Comment: This is a very common situation. Its too late now to do anything about it. But in normally serialization (boost serialization) it takes into account version for backwards compatibility.